# How to change the font size for the Expression Builder in SSIS

Tags: fonts, ssis, font-size, expressionbuilder

When using SQL Server Integration Services, I like to keep things flexible and therefore I keep any hard coded names in variables. This means using the expression builder quite a lot, but the problem is the font size for the actual Expression is way too small, especially when writing code.

I find myself copying and pasting between SSIS and Notepad++ a lot, There must be a way to adjust the font size but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: use the tool that I like the most SSIS Expression Editor & Tester, also from CodePlex: http://expressioneditor.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to grab BIDSHelper. It's a free addin to visual studio. When editing variables, you have a new pop up window to handle expressions. It gives you  a bit more real estate to work with. It unfortunately won't help with the derived column transformations. I find that if my expressions scroll off the pane, that's usually an indicator it's time to push the logic into a script transformation.

http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/

Comment: Ctrl key + mouse wheel inside the Expression Editor - sweet. Exactly what I was looking for, plus lots of nice features. I love the way that you can add a variable from the Expression Editor without having to close the form and an Expression library.

Answer (score 3):

use this standalone application that allows you to easily develop and test expressions. It is like a workbench to quickly try things without having to open a package or mess up the one your currently working on. It is designed to be easily portable, just extract the files and run, but it does require SQL Server Integration Services to be installed on the machine.

[application](http://expressioneditor.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a stand-alone application, try BiXpress, Community Edition. It integrates itself into the Visual Studio (or BIDS) and is free: http://pragmaticworks.com/Portals/0/ProductInstallers/bixpress_x86_x64_community.msi

It has more features than you were looking for.

Comment: Nice set of features, love the idea of the expression library and code reuse, but that price tag!

Comment: The Expression Library is included in the [Community Edition](http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/BI-xPress/Compare-Editions.aspx) which is the free version.